# Drain line adapter recommendation for reverse osmosis kit + dishwasher?

Tags: drain, kitchen-sink

I want to put in a reverse osmosis kit under my kitchen sink, and it requires a waste line tied into the main drain line of the kitchen sink. There's already a dishwasher drain line hooked up to the main drain line as seen in the picture:

[image]

I see there are drain line adapters I could buy which would allow me to connect my RO quick-connect and dishwasher to the same drain point:

[https://www.amazon.com/Watts-Premier-164020-Plumbing-Adapter/dp/B009XDMEK4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1486343558&sr=8-1&keywords=drain+line+adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009XDMEK4)

but I'm not sure if the adapter will fit with the copper drain line that's already hooked up. It looks like a 1/2" copper pipe. Anyone know if this adapter will be compatible?

Thanks

Comment: My RO system came with everything. I drilled a hole in the drain, inserted the tube and put the clamp over it. All done.

Comment: Hi yeah I just didn't want to drill a hole into the current waste line, I'm just paranoid that I won't do it correctly and I'll have a leak.

Comment: The hole will be at the top of the drain line. If sealed correctly with the saddle seal, no leak should occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That short piece of black rubber hose (with 2 hose clamps) that is included with the adapter in your link should attach directly to the copper pipe. Then you clamp your dishwasher hose to the proper size barbed tube; the RO drain uses the quick disconnect.

If the black hose is too big, use an adapter:

[image]

You should know that your dishwasher drain should be equipped with an *air gap*, or at least put an anti-siphon loop in there:

[image]

diagram stolen shamelessly from the web

Comment: Hi, yeah it turns out the black rubber hose is too big for the copper pipe. You mentioned the "adapter" that I could use to reduce its size so it'll fit the copper pipe. Does that have a name I could tell someone at a hardware store, or "black rubber hose adapter" is what I tell them? Thanks